Notepad++ regex to insert character to multiple places in the line
I have a structured file where every line has the same format. I need to insert the same character multiple positions in the line and apply the same to all the lines. I have a list of positions where characters need to be inserted. The position is actually character after which my character needs to go.
For example positions are: 2,5,7,11,15 and character is ;
Line:
GO12 ABCDEFG 32

Result:
GO;12 ;AB;CDEF;G 32;

But line two may be (first character is space):
 A BC TEST  121

And result should be:
 A; BC; T;EST ;  121;

Everything I could find is based on repeating distance or finding a character/word around which the insert happens. Here only the positions are constant. Most of the text is variable.

This isn't a task for a regex. Regexes match patterns, and you don't have a suitable pattern for matching.

Replace ^(..)(...)(..)(....)(....) with \1;\2;\3;\4;\5;.

From Notepad++ docs :

Notepad++ is capable of recording some of your actions you perform while editing a document, and replaying those later on to avoid having to repeat that sequence of actions. This is called a macro and can save a great deal of time. Macros can be played once, or multiple times, even as long as is required to run through an entire document. ...

This means - Notepad++ Macros only playback your keyboard actions. You also need to know exactly where your cursor is.

Set the cursor in line 1 to position 1 e.g. Strg+Home
From the main menu go to Macro > Start Recording
Use the cursor movement keys and add your delimiter ; and repeat these steps. (Loop 2x, 3x, 2x, 4x, 4x cursor and in each case the separator)
Jump to the beginning of the line Alt+Home
Go down one line
Stop the macro recording

From the main menu execute Macro > Run a Macro Multiple Times and select Run until the end of file. This is resulting in:

As mentioned in comments RegEx is possible too e.g. ^([A-Za-z0-9 ]{2})([A-Za-z0-9 ]{3}) replaced with \1;\2;. Customize it for your needs.
